# Asc or desc by clicking in php using mysql

Tags: php, jquery

By clicking on userid in the table column i want to asc or desc using php controller can it be done?

1. IN CONTROLLER

   ```
         if(isset($_GET['sortOrder'])){    
             $reverse = ($_GET['sortOrder'] == 'desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';    
             $okdata = DB::table('adminblogs')->orderBy('user_id', $reverse)->get();    
             return view("adminblog.index")->with("adminblogs", $okdata);
         }
   ```
2. IN VIEW

   ```
         <table id="example" class="table table-bordered">
           <thead> <tr>
                           <th>ID</th>
                           <th>TITLE</th>

                           <th><a id="sort" href="{{url('admin?sortOrder=asc')}}">USER ID</a></th>
                           <th>DELETE</th>
                       </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>


               @foreach($adminblogs as $blog)                  
                   <tr>
                       <td>{{ $blog->id }}</td>
                       <td>{{ $blog->title }}</td>
                       <td>{{ $blog->user_id }}</td>
                       <td>
                       @if(Auth::id() == $blog->user_id)
                       <a href="{{ url('admin/destroy/'.$blog->id.'/'.$blog->user_id) }}" class="btn btn-danger" >DELETE</a>
                       @else
                           <a href="{{ url('admin/destroy/'.$blog->id.'/'.$blog->user_id) }}" class="disabled btn btn-danger" >DELETE</a>
                       @endif

                       </td>
                   </tr>


               @endforeach
   ```

Comment: do you mind, if the page reloads

Comment: It's okay No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `thead` like below

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>TITLE</th>
    <th><a id="sort" href="{{url('admin?sortOrder='.($_GET['sortOrder'] == 'desc') ? 'asc' : 'desc')}}">USER ID</a></th>
    <th>DELETE</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a datatable for dispaying the data in your webpage. Using datatable you don't have to make a request to your server. This is a best practice rather than making a request to server on every click. Your requirement comes by default in datatable plugin. Just go through this link. https://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

Datatable fails when there's a large collection of records because then you have to fetch all the collection on clientside